# an error in uninstall a package in ubuntu

Tags: dpkg, uninstall

I create a package on Ubuntu (Ubuntu 20). During installation, it calls preinst.sh and postinst.sh; in uninstll, "apt purge packagename" calls prerm.sh. When running postrm.sh, I get an error "pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1". Is there installation log in Ubuntu so that I can see what error it is? Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you not just run and debug the script normally?

Comment: Can you provide a pointer/additional information on how to debug the script during uninstall? Thanks

Comment: I "debug" the script using the "primitive way". I comment all scripts, line by line. I found one place that error is gone, but I am still checking. Interesting enough. I found one line of code that may cause the error. however, when I run this line in a separate script, it works. Maybe script in the install/uninstall is a subset of bash scripts?

Comment: I am a newbie in Linux package installation. Please forgive me if I ask "simple" questions. Thanks

Comment: what line is causing problems?

Comment: ubuntustr=$(cat /etc/*release | grep NAME | grep ubuntu)

Comment: what error is this causing?

Comment: pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Comment: no, when you just run the script, with that line in it. Do you get any kind of error? I tried running it on wsl, and I get *two* lines, but only when I switch `ubuntu` to `Ubuntu`, otherwise I get none. Can the fact that you're not getting only one line be the problem? What are you doing with this variable afterwards? what do you expect to be stored in the variable?

Comment: Ubuntu products using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20) cannot use *deb* packages or `dpkg`.  Are you sure you mean Ubuntu Core 20, as `dpkg` and *deb* packages apply to 20.04 systems (ie. *year.month* releases)

Comment: thanks for information. I replace "cat /etc/*release" by "cat /etc/os-release".  I thought I have a fix, but I do not. When I have this line, dpkg reports an error (when I do not have this line, it works). The reason of doing this is the following.  I would need to support multiple flavors of Linux. In one flavor from China, the device name is different or with Chinese characters. As a result, I would need to check the Linux flavor.

Comment: In debugging, if I would use ubuntustr=$(cat /etc/*release | grep NAME | grep ubuntu), then I got an error. If I would use ubuntustr="", then it works ok.

Comment: Instead of using cat /etc/os-release, I use a python script that fixed the problem. It does not make too much sense, but it works. Thank you both for helping